# XPath query to only get the elements before a ' ' in each line

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, xquery

I'm trying to get some data of a website. The query I use now is:

```
//div[@class = 'TimeStamp']
Result:
2019-03-02 5:50:46
2019-03-02 5:08:52
2019-03-02 4:09:54
2019-03-02 1:52:43
2019-03-02 0:55:49
2019-03-02 0:11:04
2019-03-01 23:34:04
2019-03-01 7:01:14
2019-03-01 6:23:31
2019-03-01 5:41:01
```

The only thing I actually want are all the dates:

```
2019-03-02
2019-03-02
etc
```

I have tried accomplishing this by selecting each line individually, then using substring-before and after trying to concat them all together, like this.

```
concat(
    substring-before(
        (//div[@class = 'TimeStamp'])[1], ' '), 
    ' ', 
    substring-before(
        (//div[@class = 'TimeStamp'])[2], ' ')
)

Result:
2019-03-02 2019-03-02
```

This doesn't exactly accomplish my goal of having each date in a new line. Also, this has to happen for *n* different lines and then my method is really not optimal.

Do you people know how I can change this accordingly?

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm working in Google spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **`INDEX()`** formula for trimming the unnecessary, like:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("URL", "//div[@class = 'TimeStamp']") , , 1)
```

or maybe:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTXML("URL", "//div[@class = 'TimeStamp']"), " ") , , 1))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(TO_DATE(INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTXML(
 "https://"&C13&".op.gg/summoner/userName="&B13; 
 "//div[@class = 'TimeStamp']"); " "); ; 1));
 "yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you so much, the final solution worked perfectly